# How to use RMSE when having data normalization?

Tags: time-series, normalization, rms

I am new in machine learning and I am studying time series prediction using neural networks.

Pseudocode 1:

```
norm_data = normalize(raw_data)
train_data_in, train_data_out, test_data_in, test_data_expected = split(norm_data)
net = trainNeuralNetwork(train_data_in, train_data_out)
output = net(test_data_in)
print(rmse(test_data_expected, output))
```

Pseudocode 2:

```
norm_data = normalize(raw_data)
train_data_in, train_data_out, test_data_in, test_data_expected = split(norm_data)
net = trainNeuralNetwork(train_data_in, train_data_out)
output = net(test_data_in)
den_output = denormalize(output)                 // Added
den_expected = denormalize(train_data_expected)  // Added
print(rmse(den_expected, den_output))
```

My doubt is which code is correct ? I have to denormalize the data to apply the RMSE or not ? Many articles that I've read did not mention if the benchmark on results section was normalized or not, and if the RMSE(the papers that I've read show the efficiency through rmse) was calculated on normalized data.

I want to know this because I am measuring the efficiency of my neural networks comparing the RMSE of my results with the RMSE of the papers.

Thanks !

Comment: I would suggest that you should not denormalise the data. Why do you think you should do it?

Comment: Because when I normalizes the data, it will be rescaled, and the value of RMSE can be really different when applied with the original data format. And for me is more intuitive.

Comment: But what if your normalisation is not just linear transformation? I.e. power transformation. Denormalisation will lead to absolutely weird RMSE.

Comment: What do you mean weird RMSE ?  I think the RMSE will represent the same idea. With nomalized data or not. But with the non-normalized data the RMSE is closer to the naturalness of the data.

Comment: Finally agree with you. It is correct to do denormalisation of predicted / true values. Sorry, it did not answer your question. May be you can just try to repeat the analysis provided in papers in order to understand if they de normalise the data? Or just look at the similarity of your values and values in papers.

Comment: Thanks, did not answer but your opinion helped me. I tested and compared with one paper that I have and the results are more real when denormalize. I will keep comparing my results with other papers.